# How to access a WCF Service within my webpage in vs2010?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, wcf

I have created a simple Web Service application and used *SvcUtil.exe* to generate the two needed files named `MyService.cs` and `app.config`.

What I want to do now is be able to use this webservice from a web-app or webpage.
What I was doing until now was creating my website and creating an *angular* factory that would use *ajax* to call the various functions on a class that I used to create for the purpose of dealing with those requests only. For example I would have the following function inside a file name `fhandler.aspx.cs`:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    [ScriptService]
    public partial class fHandler: System.Web.UI.Page
    {            
        // Save Interests Stress Test in List.
        [WebMethod]
        public static string saveDataJS(string data)
        {
...
```

This would get called by an `ajax` request that would return a promise like this:

```
saveData: function(data) {
    var senddata = {
        'data': data
    };
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://' + location.host + '/fHandler.aspx/saveDataJS',
        data: senddata,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/download; charset=utf-8"
        }
    });
},
```

Now that I am using web-services though I am not sure how to approach this.
What would be the best set-up for consuming a WCF service from a webpage?

Assuming we skip the create another project inside your solution, add `MyService.cs` and `app.config` to it and add a Reference to your service, part.

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial](http://www.csharptutorial.in/34/csharp-net-how-to-consume-a-wcf-web-service-in-visual-studio-2010) once helped me a great deal with creating and consuming a WCF service.

To consume a WCF service, you simply have to add a service reference to your project. Have a look at the tutorial, it is all described with pictures.

*Solution Explorer* > *{your project}* > *Add Service Reference*.

[image: AddServiceReference]

After that, you can enter the URL of your service. Afterwards, you should be able to see all public methods your service offers:

[image: Service]

Comment: Hi Matthias, this is not closely related to my question since it is using a console application to consume the service. I am interested in having a webapp. Moreover I am interested in how to structure said webapp in a good way so as to access the service.